# Obtaining categories and subcategories joined from Mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables. One table is called `places`, this table holds different places (such as businesses, restaurants, etc...) each "place" is linked to a table called `categories`, however some categories have subcategories in a hierarchical structure (i.e. Thai Food is a subcategory of Restaurants). This system lets an admin create places and matches them with a corresponding category or subcategory.

What I would like to know is what is the best way to obtain these relations? Currently I am using JOINs and GROUP_CONCAT but I am still not getting a good result set.

These are my tables:

**places:**

```
+----+----------------+
| id | name           |
+----+----------------+
| 1  | Mings Place    |
+----+----------------+
| 2  | Halsey Library |
+----+----------------+
| 3  | Stellas USO    |
+----+----------------+
```

**places_categories_rel**:

```
+----------+-------------+
| place_id | category_id |
+----------+-------------+
| 1        | 2           |
+----------+-------------+
| 2        | 4           |
+----------+-------------+
| 3        | 3           |
+----------+-------------+
| 3        | 4           |
+----------+-------------+
```

**categories**:

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id | parent_id | name       |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 1  | null      | Restaurant |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 2  | 1         | Thai Food  |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 3  | 1         | Italian    |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 4  | null      | Government |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 5  | 4         | Library    |
+----+-----------+------------+
| 6  | 4         | Military   |
+----+-----------+------------+
```

As you can see some places are attached to a subcategory, some places are attached directly to a parent category (without subcategories), and some places have multiple subcategories which have different parent categories.

To obtain my results, I attempted the following SQL:

```
'SELECT `p`.*, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT (ca.id, "|", `ca`.`parent_id`, "|", ca.name))) as subcategories, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT (ca1.id, "|", `ca1`.`parent_id`, "|", ca1.name))) as categories
FROM `places` `p`
LEFT JOIN `places_categories_rel` `rel` ON `rel`.`place_id`=`p`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `categories` `ca` ON `ca`.`id`=`rel`.`category_id`
LEFT JOIN `categories` `ca1` ON `ca1`.`id`=`ca`.`parent_id`
GROUP BY `p`.`id`
```

But my results come up with some categories being set as subcategories or vice versa.

What I would like is to have some type of result set that would allow me to have something like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Mings Place' (length=11)
      'categories' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'name' => string 'Restaurant' (length=10)
              'subcategories' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Thai Food' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Halsey Library' (length=14)
      'categories' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'name' => string 'Government' (length=10)
              'subcategories' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Library' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'Stellas' (length=7)
      'categories' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'name' => string 'Restaurant' (length=10)
              'subcategories' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => string 'Library' (length=7)
          1 => 
            array (size=2)
              'name' => string 'Government' (length=10)
              'subcategories' => null
```

Ideally, this will all be created so that I can input filters. For example if I only want to see places with Category of Restaurants, or places with Government and Subcategory of Italian food...

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Comment: you can get all category with subcategory in recursive manner .check this .http://thecoderain.blogspot.in/2016/03/get-category-and-subcategory-tree-in.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you only have two levels of categories (e.g. no sub-subcategories), then using a JOIN can be fine.

The problem is, your data sometimes references parent categories, and sometimes references subcategories.  That's why you're getting mixed results.

To avoid mixed results, you can use something like this:

```
SELECT
  p.*,
  CONCAT(IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(c_parent...), ''), ',', IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(c_direct_parent...), '')),
  GROUP_CONCAT(c_child...),
FROM `places` AS p
  LEFT JOIN `places_categories_rel` AS rel
    ON rel.`place_id` = p.`id`
  LEFT JOIN `categories` AS c_direct_parent
    ON c_direct_parent.`id` = rel.`category_id`
    AND c_direct_parent.`parent_id` IS NULL
  LEFT JOIN `categories` AS c_child
    ON c_child.`id` = rel.`category_id`
    AND c_child.`parent_id` IS NOT NULL
  LEFT JOIN `categories` AS c_parent
    ON c_parent.`id` = c_child.`parent_id`
GROUP BY p.`id`
```

I'm not sure this is a very efficient option, but as you can see, you need to separate out "related categories that are parents" (c_direct_parent) and "related categories are are children" (c_child).

With that separation, you can now properly retrieve a list of data for the parents and the children.  For clarity, I put "..." for the GROUP_CONCAT internals.

Answer (score 1):

So Not exactly a good way but this might suffice your porblem solution

```
SELECT `p`.*,c.*
FROM `places` `p`
LEFT JOIN `places_categories_rel` `rel` ON `rel`.`place_id`=`p`.`id`
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT c1.id as childID, c1.name ChildName, c2.name as ParentName
from categories c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c2
ON c1.parent_id = c2.id)  c on c.childID= rel.category_id
```

Output:-

`id name    childID ChildName   ParentName`
`1  Mings Place 2   Thai Food   Restaurant`
`3  Stellas 3   Italian Restaurant`
`2  Halsey Library  4   Government  NULL`
`3  Stellas 4   Government  NULL`

Now you have to think how you can group by name.

A workaround for this, is if parenty is empty replace it wil blank string otherwise with parentCategory name.

```
SELECT `p`.*,GROUP_CONCAT(ChildName) as Category,GROUP_CONCAT(if(ParentName IS NULL ," ",ParentName ) ) as parent
FROM `places` `p`
LEFT JOIN `places_categories_rel` `rel` ON `rel`.`place_id`=`p`.`id`
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT c1.id as childID, c1.name ChildName, c2.name as ParentName
from categories c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN categories c2
ON c1.parent_id = c2.id)  c on c.childID= rel.category_id
GROUP BY `p`.`id`
```

producing output as

`id name    Category    parent`
`1  Mings Place Thai Food   Restaurant`
`2  Halsey Library  Government`
`3  Stellas Italian,Government  Restaurant,`